# What's the cohomology of disjoint union of two circles

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I am computing the cohomology of $T^2$ by Meyer-Vietoris sequence. $T^2$ can be seen as the union of two open sets U and V s.t. U and V are diffeomorphic to a cylinder respectively. Thus U$\cap$V is a disjoint union of two cylinders which is homotopic to a disjoint union of two circles. In order to apply Meyer-Vietoris sequence I need to figure out the cohomology of disjoint union of two circles, but I am stuck on it for a long time, can you give me some ideas? Thank you!

Comment: The cohomology of a disjoint union is the direct sum of the cohomologies.

Comment: @LeeMosher thank you, can you show me how to show that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider the Mayer-Vietoris long exact sequence of $A\cup B$, and you assume that co-homology of empty set is $0$ , this will give you a direct isomorphism $H^n(A\cup B)= H^n(A) \oplus H^n(B)$.

So your answer would be $\mathbb{Z\oplus Z}$.

Comment: A minor not-really issue: better write $H^n(A) \times H^n(B)$ instead, because cohomology is contravariant, so it sends coproduct to products. It's not true that $H^n(\coprod A_i) \cong \bigoplus H^n(A_i)$, for infinite collection $\{A_i\}$ for example.

Comment: yes, you are right,  since here I only used two sets, that is why I used that notation of direct sum

Comment: Yeah, like I said, it's not an issue in this case.

Comment: Thank you, but why it is Z not R?

Comment: What is the 1st cohomology group of $S^1$ ???

Comment: Sorry, isn't it R? http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~andrews/DG/DG_chap15.pdf p.146

Comment: depends upon what underlying ring structure you are considering... it is in geneal $R$ if you consider chohology w.r.t $R$... in this case I took integer coeffcient, so I got $Z$..