# On the homology of manifolds with boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology, manifolds-with-boundary

Suppose that $M$ is a smooth manifold with a boundary. Let $\mathrm{int}(M):=M\setminus\partial M$ be its interior. Is there a relation between the (relative or absolute) homology of $M$ and the homologies of $\mathrm{int}(M)$ and $\partial M$?

The naive guess $H_k(M) \overset{?}{\cong} H_k(\mathrm{int}(M))\oplus H_k(\partial M)$
doesn't work. E.g. as mentioned by @coudy in the comments, if $M$ is a disk this is obviously false.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Try with a disk. Its boundary is a circle.

Comment: @ArcticChar $M=\mathrm{int}(M)\sqcup\partial M$ and $H_*(A\sqcup B)=H_*(A)\oplus H_*(B)$.

Comment: Your equation is clearly false for general $A$ and $B$. Take a look at Coudy's example.

Comment: @ArcticChar According to [this math.SE asnwer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1560111/1106588) it holds in cohomology. Then we can Poincaré dualize both sides at the cost of having relative homology on the LHS. It still wouldn't work though for coudy's example. So I'm confused

Comment: In that link they have disjoint union, with the implicit assumption on the topology of the disjoint union.

Comment: @ArcticChar can you elaborate? I updated the question, hopefully it's better now.

Comment: If $X$ is (as a set) the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$, we say that it has the topology of the disjoint union if both $A$ and $B$ are open in $X$ (and therefore also closed). This is clearly not the case for a manifold and its boundary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inclusion $\mathrm{int}(M)\rightarrow M$ is a homotopy equivalence. This follows from the existence of a collar neighborhood of $\partial M$ in $M$. Thus, $H_i(\mathrm{int}(M))\rightarrow H_i(M)$ and $H^i(M)\rightarrow H^i(\mathrm{int}(M))$ are isomorphisms for all $i\ge0$. The relation between $H_i(\partial M)$ and $H_i(M)$ is not quite so clear, I think. There is, of course, a long exact pair sequence of the form $\dotsc\rightarrow H_i(\partial M)\rightarrow H_i(M)\rightarrow H_i(M,\partial M)\rightarrow\dotsc$. Furthermore, Lefschetz duality allows you to identify $H_i(M,\partial M)\cong H^{n-i}_c(M)$. Thus, the sequence has one term depending on the homotopy type of $\partial M$, one term depending on the homotopy type of $M$ and one term depending on the proper homotopy type of $M$. If $M$ is compact, then of course $H_c^{n-i}(M)=H^{n-i}(M)$, so two terms each in the sequence only depend on the homotopy type of $M$ and the third term each on the homotopy type of $\partial M$.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! Can I express Lefschetz duality in terms of only (co)homology? Or at least their dimensions? I.e. does it also hold that $\mathrm{dim}H_i(M,\partial M) = \mathrm{dim}H_{n-i}(M,\partial M)$? or something along these lines?

Comment: If $M$ is compact and you take field coefficients, then yes, simply because cohomology and homology are isomorphic then. To understand the torsion parts, you have to use the universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: Sorry, I got  bit confused again. Can you elaborate what you mean by "homology and cohomology are isomorphic then"?

Comment: For $F$ a field and $X$ space, $H^i(X;F)\cong\mathrm{Hom}_F(H_i(X;F),F)$ for all $i\ge0$, i.e. homology and cohomology are dual. If $X=M$ is a compact manifold, these vector spaces are finite-dimensional and a finite-dimensional vector space and its dual are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

There is a relation between the relative cohomology of $M$ with respect to its boundary and the homology of its boundary $\partial X$, called [Lefschetz duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_duality). Given a compact orientable manifold $X$ of dimension $n$, for all $q$, there is an isomorphism
$$H^q(X,\partial X) \simeq H_{n-q}(X).$$

This can be used, for example, to obtain a relation between the homology of $X$, its boundary $\partial X$ and its double $2X$ obtained by gluing $X$ to itself along its boundary. This implies the following relation between the Euler characteristics,
$$
\chi(2X) = 2\chi(X)-\chi(\partial X).
$$

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't after Lefschetz duality, I knew that. I would like to get something stronger than just a relation of Euler characteristics, about individual Betti numbers, of $M$, $\mathrm{int}(M)$ and $\partial M$. Also this doesn't use anything the interior of $M$ at all.

Comment: Under suitable assumptions, $H^q(X, \partial X)$ is the cohomology of the interior of $X$.

Comment: But this is just recycling Poincaré and Lefschetz duality. I don't see how this gives me information about the Betti numbers, that I couldn't get by using those two.